# Store an object with an array inside?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to store an `object` with an `array[id] = "certain value"`, so that every single user has a list of favorite things ?

What I'm trying to achieve is having a data object with undefined values at first, and filling them in, so for example Jack and Sam could have an assigned favorite movie saved.

I tried something like this with no success:

Data.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    return {
        favMovie: ""
    }
};
```

App.js:

```
var person [] = data();

//1st person
person[811767132257839].favMovie = "Matrix";

//2nd person
person[107230716367889].favMovie = "Kill Bill";

//3rd person
person[973676332752239].favMovie = "Avatar";

...

console.log( "Favorite movie: " + person[id].favMovie );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you want any arrays at all, just objects.

```
// Create an object that we'll keep person objects in
var personData = {};

// Add a person object to it for person ID #123
personData[123] = {};

// Set person #123's favorite movie:
personData[123].favMovie = "Avatar";

// Add a different person; this time, we'll add the movie at
// the same time
personData[234] = {
    favMovie: "Matrix"
};
```

When using objects as maps like that, sometimes people create the objects using `Object.create(null)` to avoid them having any inherited properties (like `toString` and `valueOf` and `constructor`):

```
person[123] = Object.create(null);
person[123].favMovie = "Avatar";
```

In ES2015 (aka "ES6"), you might want to use a `Map` rather than an object for the map of people:

```
var personData = new Map();
```

...and then use `set` and `get` for the individual person objects.

If the individual person objects get complicated, you might use a constructor function and associated prototype for them, using either ES5 syntax:

```
function Person() {
    // ...
}
Person.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    // ...
};
```

...or ES2015 syntax:

```
class Person {
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
    doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then creating them:

```
personData[123] = new Person();
// or if using Map
personData.set(123, new Person());
```

---

Side note: Even when we write them as numbers, the keys (property names) in objects are always *strings* (unless you use ES2015 `Symbol`s, which you probably wouldn't here). In contrast, keys in an ES2015 `Map` can be anything. Key equality in `Map` instances is determined using the special ["same value zero"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm (which is basically `===` except that `NaN` is equal to itself [whereas it isn't in `===`]).